# javascript behavior for '\352' decimal value

Tags: javascript, salt

while checking login page, I found the following JS code

```
hexMD5('\232' + document.login.password.value + '\305\334\122\134\352');
```

so, I am asking about `\352` will it occupy one byte and hence cause overflow and yield `96` or java script interpreter promote it to `short` to preserve its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have bytes, shorts, or integers*, it has only the [`Number` type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5), which is a double-precision IEEE-754 number. But that's not really relevant to the code you've shown unless something uses `charCodeAt` on the string to get the corresponding code point for one of the characters in it, because you're defining code points (loosely, "characters") in a string, not numbers. [Characters in JavaScript are 16-bit entities](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4), so the octal escape `'\352'` encodes character 234 decimal, which obviously readily fits within the character's 16-bit range.

Side note: Octal escapes are not part of the main standard and are disallowed in strict mode. They're part of a [non-normative annex](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.2) to the specification. I'd recommend using hex escapes or unicode escapes rather than octal ones.

* Well, JavaScript does have 32-bit integers as a *transient* thing during some bit-related calculations, such as those performed by the `&` and `|` operators.

Comment: first, thanks about this detailed answer, secondly, I have Java background, that's why I thought java script will have similar concepts, and for the answer, you are saying that this value is an octal literal and not a decimal literal?

Comment: @DrAhmedJava: Correct. With `\DDD` (where `D` is a digit), the digits give a value in octal. `\xDD` (a hex escape) uses hex, and `\uDDDD` (a Unicode escape) also uses hex. There is no character escape that uses decimal. More: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4

Comment: that is irrelevant and not a chat, but I am so grateful for people who spend time to take other people's hands. just Thanks.

Comment: @DrAhmedJava: ?? What isn't relevant?

Comment: NO, you got me wrong, I am grateful to YOU,I just meant thank you, I didn't mean your comment is irrelevant, I mean my thanks may be irrelevant as this is not a chat.